# OpenHtmlToPdf Access is denied with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, openhtmltopdf

In my ASP.NET application (.NET Framework 4.7) I'm using `OpenHtmlToPdf` for creating PDF based on the pages in the website.

It is working locally but not in the server production: I have the following error:

> Exception type: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception Exception
>   message: Access is denied
>
> Stack trace:    at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo
>   startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() at
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at
>   OpenHtmlToPdf.HtmlToPdfConverterProcess.Convert(ConversionSource
>   conversionSource) at
>   OpenHtmlToPdf.Pdf.DocumentBuilder.ReadContentUsingTemporaryFile(String
>   temporaryFilename)

I think the problem is related to `wkhtmltopdf` because OpenHtmlToPdf is using this library to generate the PDF. The code is pretty simple.

```
    var pdf = Pdf.From(html)
                 .WithGlobalSetting("orientation", "Landscape")
                 .WithObjectSetting("web.defaultEncoding", "utf-8")
                 .Content();

    return File(pdf, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "Reference.pdf");
```

Then, how can I generate the PDF?

Comment: In which folder are you trying to create that file? It seems to be the root of your site. Usually this folder is not writable. Did you try to create that file in the APP_DATA folder?

Comment: Yes but no changes

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

OpenHTMLToPDF use Path.GetTempPath() and Guid.NewGuid() to create a temp file. Make sure your running process has sufficient privelegdes to write to the path returned by Path.GetTempPath();

For reference here is the source code responsible for creating the temp file name, and writing it.

```
//inside TemporaryPdf class
public static string TemporaryFilePath() 
{
  return Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "OpenHtmlToPdf", TemporaryPdf.TemporaryFilename());
}

private static string TemporaryFilename()
{
  return Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N") + ".pdf";
}
```

And then it is used when calling Content

```
  // inside the Pdf class
  public byte[] Content()
  {
    return this.ReadContentUsingTemporaryFile(TemporaryPdf.TemporaryFilePath());
  }

  private byte[] ReadContentUsingTemporaryFile(string temporaryFilename)
  {
    this._globalSettings["out"] = temporaryFilename;
    HtmlToPdfConverterProcess.ConvertToPdf(this._html, this._globalSettings, this._objectSettings);
    byte[] numArray = TemporaryPdf.ReadTemporaryFileContent(temporaryFilename);
    TemporaryPdf.DeleteTemporaryFile(temporaryFilename);
    return numArray;
  }
```

The rest of the code can be found on GitHub here:
[OpenHTMLToPDF](https://github.com/vilppu/OpenHtmlToPdf)

Comment: I'm able to solve this by allow access to the folder `C:\Windows\Temp\OpenHtmlToPdf`

Comment: your comment should be the approved solution, cheers